# win10 cannot detect the package of egg installed by pip in conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda

I installed a package **mas-ast** by downloading it from GitHub and using `python setup.py install` in my conda virtual environment, which is named `env_me`. I can show that package with command `pip show mas-ast`, but it doesn't appear when I try to list it from the Windows command line. Instead, I get this result:

```
C:\Users\sonictl>activate env_me && pip show mas-ast
Name: mas-ast
Version: 2.0.3
Summary: 
Home-page: https://github.com/decoxviii/mas-ast
Author: decyi
Author-email: decyi@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\sonictl\anaconda3\envs\env_me\lib\site-packages\mas_ast-2.0.3-py3.7.egg
Requires: aiohttp, colorama, docopt
Required-by:

(env_me) C:\Users\sonictl>mas-ast -h
'mas-ast' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I run that pip-installed egg in windows cmd or pyCharm Console?

Comment: Can you import the module from python?

Comment: I cannot find the source repository and inspect the code. Does the packages install any scripts? Are these scripts installed into a directory added to `$PATH`? Check the directory `c:\users\sonictl\anaconda3\envs\env_me\Scripts` — is the script `mas-ast` there?

Comment: @phd, it does exist in the `c:\Users\sonictl\Anaconda3\envs\env_me\Scripts` but not like other files with `.exe` or `.py` as their suffix, the `mas-ast` file has no suffix.

Comment: on linux, or linux-like os, the code can be executed in that `env_me` and `mas-ast`;  But on windows, the `mas-ast.exe` file can be manually generated by the `pyinstaller` tool ([link](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)) and be moved into a directory added to `$PATH`, such as `c:\users\sonictl\anaconda3\envs\env_me\Scripts`

Comment: have a try with the `python -m mas-ast`